# Finding absolute Max and Min of $f(x,y)=x^4+9y^4$

Tags: calculus

I have found the critica's point $(0,0)$ but the hessian matrix doesn't give any information, because the eigenvalues are zero. Can anyone give a method how to handle this problem?

Comment: PS i had to look on the disk x^2+4y^2≤ 1

Comment: The minimum is $0$, obviously. To compute the maximum of $x^4+9y^4$ on $x^2+4y^2\leqslant1$, show that $$x^4+9y^4\leqslant(x^2+4y^2)^2$$ and conclude by considering the point $$(x,y)=(1,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

the function goes to infinity if $x$ or $y$ or both growth. Further we get
$$\frac{x^4+9y^4}{2}\geq \sqrt{9x^4y^4}=3x^2y^2\geq 0$$ and the equal sign holds if $$x=y=0$$
you can consider the function on the curve $$x^2+4y^2=1$$
under the condition we get the searched Maximum $1$

Comment: " we get the searched Maximum 1" Why? You know, like, giving a *proof*...